# confirmation dialog based on results from java code execution

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, dialog

I have a query about web development. Don't have development knowledge and trying build a web application.

The requirement is:
When the user clicks a submit button after enter data in 2-3 html input textboxes, I would like to pop-up a confirmation dialog based on results from some java code e.g. if the data entered is already existing in server, I would like to ask: "Hey! this data is already there. Are you sure you wanted merge the input with existing data?".

I am not sure how I can do it. I am using Java, Tomcat, Eclipse, JSP, HTML, Javascript in my application. I know I can invoke javascript functions on click of button, but how to generate a confirmation dialog based on some processing of the input data, and based on confirmation, go ahead with full processing.

Comment: This can be done using Ajax. Here's a good starting point to learn about it: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686/1065197). It would be better to first learn the basics about web development: [design patterns on web applications](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3541077/1065197), specially MVC, [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197) and [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

Comment: Also check out http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html

Comment: @mplungjan I agree that a framework can help to leverage this job. Still IMO it would be better learning the concepts and how to apply them and then use any tool/framework to help with this job.

Answer (score -1):

To do conformation in javascript, you use the prompt function. You would do the following

```
function askForConformation()  {
     var ask = prompt("Are you sure that you want to do this?");

     // making sure for both cases
     if(ask === "Y" || ask === "y") {
        // do whatever you need
     }
     else {
        // do whatever else
     }
}
```

Comment: This will just prompt the user for a yes/no action. If you read the question carefully, OP wants/needs to do this based on a request to the data before being saved (that should be done using ajax).